# How to make a button in grouped records in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I have created a tree view for `stock.move` model, which by default is grouped by the field `picking_id`.

Now I would like to know how to create a button in the line on which you click for deploying its content. I put an example:

> I have *Move A1*, *Move B1*, *Move B2*, *Move C1* and *Move C2*,
>   grouped by `picking_id`, so I have three groups: *Picking A*, *Picking
>   B* and *Picking C*. Now I would like to have a button in *Picking A*,
>   *Picking B* and *Picking C* lines, but not in *Move A1*, *B1*, *B2*, etc... The button should get its respective picking ID value and call
>   a method (it would be great a Python method, with possibility of using
>   `env`).

Anyone has any idea of how can this be managed or where could I start looking for information about this?

**EDIT**

I attach an image of my current view:

[image: What I would like is to add buttons on each WH/IN/XXXXX line, which is the picking, and this buttons should call a method and pass it their respective picking IDs to know on which button the user clicked]

*What I would like is to add buttons on each WH/IN/XXXXX line, which is the picking, and these buttons should call a method and pass it their respective picking IDs to know on which button the user clicked.*

Comment: This is a little hard to visualize...can you share a mockup image? and your current `treeview` code

Comment: @danidee I attached my current view.